# How to Create GWT CellTable Dynamically with entity

Tags: gwt, gwt-celltable

i have a problem, i need to insert into celltable rows of entity persistent, I have seen all the examples of celltable in Google Developer's Guide and searched a lot to do so without entity class.
this is my entity (Package entity.commun):

```
public class Eleve implements java.io.Serializable{

@PrimaryKey

        @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY) private String email;

    @Persistent private String nom;

    @Persistent private String prenom;
    @Persistent private char sexe;
    @Persistent private String adresse;
    @Persistent private String codePostal;
    @Persistent private String dateNaissance;
    @Persistent private String lieuNaissance;
    @Persistent private String groupe;
    @Persistent private String emailParent;



    public Eleve(String nom,String prenom,char sexe,String adresse,String codePostal, String dateNaissance,String lieuNaissance,String email,String emailParent) {

        this.email=email;
        this.nom=nom;
        this.prenom=prenom;
        this.sexe=sexe;
        this.adresse=adresse;
        this.codePostal=codePostal;
        this.dateNaissance=dateNaissance;
        this.lieuNaissance=lieuNaissance;
        this.emailParent=emailParent;
        this.groupe=null;

    }
//Getters and Setters   

}
```

my celltable in package Client:

```
CellTable<Eleve> cellTable_Eleve = new CellTable<Eleve>();
        Panel_Read_Eleve.add(cellTable_Eleve , 0, 32);
        cellTable_Eleve .setSize("189px", "156px");
```

when i compile the project, there's a lot of errors: 
did you forget to inherit a required module?

I need help, i m starter on GWT developpement
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello as in Bonjour Monsieur,

It looks like you need to create some kind of DTO in your client package for the Eleve entity.

For exemple, you would fetch Eleve lists through remote calls (JSON, RPC, RequestFactory, etc.)  and return let's say a list of EleveDTO objects.

It looks like [RequestFactory](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory) would be a nice fit for you.

Comment: After 5 years i found your response, thanks for your attention. When i started this project, i didn't have enough knowledge about GWT and the differences between client package and server package, i was developping GWT like working with Java swing. I used my persistable Entity in the UI layer directly. So the compilation fails, because all persistence layer dependency will be compiled to Java script.
I shouldn't do that. I had must use a kind of DTO like you said.
Now i'm quite experimented with GWT. The question that i asked make me laugh.